# Microsoft Visual C# Express .Content

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a game in C# in Microsoft Visual C# express and I'm using the string label .Content and I seem to be getting an error on the program saying that there is no definition how can this be fixed?

```
        //Label contents...
        label1.Content = "100";
        label2.Content = "200";
        label3.Content = "300";
        label4.Content = "400";
        label5.Content = "500";
        label6.Content = "800";
        label7.Content = "1000";
        label8.Content = "5000";
        label9.Content = "8000";
        label10.Content = "10000";
        label11.Content = "15000";
        label12.Content = "20000";
        label13.Content = "30000";
        label14.Content = "50000";
        label15.Content = "60000";
        label16.Content = "80000";
        label17.Content = "100000";
        label18.Content = "130000";
        label19.Content = "160000";
        label20.Content = "180000";
        label21.Content = "200000";
```

i have to make it work with this

```
if ( label1.Container.ToString() == p)
        {
            label1.Content += "     (lost)";
```

Comment: Are you doing this in a Forms project or a WPF project?

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net?

Comment: Forms project. @TiesonT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`System.Windows.Forms.Label`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.aspx) class doesn't have a property called `Content` which is why you are receiving your compile error.

Just guessing at what you want to do with this I would say you're looking for [`Label.Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cs4xb3d.aspx).

Update:

I believe [`Content`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content.aspx) is the common WPF equivalent (roughly) to [`Control.Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.text.aspx) in Winforms. If you got it to work before then you're either using a different set of controls *or* you're not using WinForms.

Comment: so if i have a `picturebox.Content` id have to use `picturebox.image` instead?

Comment: Considering the `System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox` doesn't have a `Content` property, I'd say yes. I think I see where you're going though; if you expect a common property to set regardless of control type then either use WPF _or_ (do what my previous employer did) wrap the WinForms controls in a WPF like facade.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. i appreciate you taking your time helping a nooby like me.

Comment: We've all been there at one point or another. I'm sure a lot of the experts here at SO would appreciate that you attempt to use the MSDN documentation before asking questions though. They get rather bored by the trivial questions about _What does an `if` statement do_ and the like. I don't mind so much though.